# Unable to get mov ax,3 int 33h to work in graphics mode

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I'm trying to draw a rectangle in graphics mode (13h) and check whether it was clicked at any time or not, if it was ever clicked I would like to go to "rectangleWasClicked:" , this was my approach for this, however it doesn't seem to work (in terms of getting the drawn rectangle clicked).

```
getAction:
                      
    mov  ax, 0001h  
    int  33h ;Show Mouse

    checkMousePointer ; This simply does: mov ax,3 int 33h

     drawPlatform  65, 85, 15, 10, 240 ;This draws a rectangle, it takes x,y, color, height, width

     cmp bx,1 ;The user clicked, we need to check if that was on the rectangle
     ;shr cx
     jnz getAction ;It's not, so we keep checking

    ;Checking if the click was on the rectangle

     cmp cx,65
     jb done

     cmp cx,305
     ja done

     cmp dx,85
     jb done

     cmp dx,95
     ja done

     JMP rectangleWasClicked

     done:
    jmp getAction
```

I even tried shr cx, 1 to accommodate to the fact that the macro might be using a 640x200 resolution, however that didn't seem to work.
I also tried comparing bx to 0 instead of 1 so that whenever the mouse hovers in the region I specified it goes to the label however no matter where I hover in the whole screen it does nothing.
Any thoughts?

This is the drawPlatform macro:

```
    drawPlatform macro x, y, color, height, width ;x, y are the starting position (top left corner)
       local whilePlatformBeingDrawn
        mov cx,x                        
        mov dx,y                                
        whilePlatformBeingDrawn:
            drawPixel_implicit color
            inc cx ;the x-coordinate
            checkDifference cx, x, width ;Keep adding Pixels till Cx-P_x=widthPlatform
         JNG whilePlatformBeingDrawn 
            mov cx, x
            inc dx
            checkDifference dx, y, height
        JNG whilePlatformBeingDrawn
    endm drawPlatform
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like *drawPlatform* is trashing `cx` and `dx` before you compare them to mouse coordinates. If you `push cx` `push dx` before calling *drawPlatform* and  then `pop dx` `pop cx` afterwards, it should work.
Doesn't TASM come with Turbo Debugger? Or at least if you have some print routines you could put some screen messages in strategic places in the code to see the flow of events.

Comment: Shouldn't they not better preserve those `CX` and `DX` registers **inside** the macro code; so not "before calling *drawPlatform". Less fuss if they keep everything nicely together.

Comment: It looks like to me that the mov ax,3 int 33h should have come after the drawPlatform to avoid the problem altogether. I didn't notice that at first so I just put in the quick fix above.